# Can I get active users on instead of the last 30 minutes from the Google Analytics Realtime API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google Analytics Realtime API and have written a script that gets a certain event back but it's using data from the last 30 min. Is there a way to get the real time active users?

Thanks!

Comment: 30 minutes is default session lifetime. Google cannot be sure that a user is inactive before the session is over (he might be looking very hard a particular page without further interaction), so I'd say the answer is "no".